# ajax flot div refresh consecutively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, flot

I have 5 `<div>` elements for flot which I would like to refresh via ajax. During the ajax process the divs show loading icons. The problem is, that I want to refresh the divs consecutively. If I alert after ajax.complete it works.

My example code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="stats-1"></div>
<div id="stats-2"></div>
<div id="stats-3"></div>
<div id="stats-4"></div>
<div id="stats-5"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax/ajax.get.stats.php',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                data: { ID : i },
                complete: function() {
                    $('#stats-'+i]).removeClass('block-opt-refresh');
                },
                success: onOutboundReceived
            });

            function onOutboundReceived(data) {
                var length = data.length;
                var finalData = data;
                var options = {
                    series: {
                        lines: {
                            show: true,
                            lineWidth: 2, 
                            fill: true,
                            fillColor: {
                                colors: [{
                                    opacity: 0.2
                                },{
                                    opacity: 0.01
                                }]
                            } 
                        },
                        points: {
                            show: true
                        },
                        shadowSize: 2
                    },
                    legend:{
                      show: false
                    },
                    grid: {
                        labelMargin: 10,
                        axisMargin: 500,
                        hoverable: true,
                        clickable: true,
                        tickColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.22)",
                        borderWidth: 0
                    },
                    yaxis: {
                        ticks: 5,
                        tickDecimals: 0,
                        min: 0
                    },
                    xaxis: {
                        ticks: 24,
                        tickDecimals: 0,
                        min: 0
                    }
                };
                $.plot($("#stats-"+i]), finalData, options);
```

Comment: the way you are doing it, you can't determine the order in which ajax calls will complete. Its quite possible in some cases last ajax call completes before first one.

Comment: It doesn't matter ;) I want to remove every loading icon from the div after every ajax call. Now the icons are removed when all ajax calls are finished.

Comment: async: false will wait until the server side work is completed before updating the screen.

Comment: If I do a 'async: false' I get the error: Invalid dimensions for plot, width = null, height = null